Is law properly considered "technology"?
In season 2, episode 7 of Slate's Slow Burn podcast, lawyer & author Linda Hisrhman says (@ 20m28s):

A big achievement for feminism was to bring the social technology of law into the single-family dwelling.

(emphasis mine)
Within the legal community, is this characterization of law, as a form of technology, a radical, or mainstream viewpoint?

I see that jurisprudence is marked "do not use," but it was recommended to me in meta when I asked about posting this question, and it's not clear to me (a layman) which of the successor tags is the right fit.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Within the legal community, is this characterization of law, as a form
of technology, a radical, or mainstream viewpoint?

Economists, anthropologists, historians, and "social entrepreneurs" often describe law as a technology, and it isn't an uncommon view among political scientists and political activists, so in that sense it is a mainstream viewpoint. It also isn't a particularly new concept. I've seen this concept in books that I've read from at least the 1960s onward, analogizing the work of lobbyists and lawyers to that of engineers dealing with physical technologies.
The legal community has no reason to think much about the question one way or the other. It is really only a description that makes sense from a legislative or policy making perspective.
The main way that lawyers might be engaged in the question is in connection with efforts to obtain business method patents for what are basically legal innovations. There, it is more of a question of the substantive limits of patent law than it is one of terminology or a conceptual framework. Some recent innovations in patent law have disfavored many patents of this kind.
For example, tax strategy patents were expressly prohibited by legislation in the year 2011.

"Social technology" is to Social Science what technology is to science; it is the application of the principles of social science to achieve desired goals in human societies.
The "social technology of law" is therefore the conscious use of legal and judicial systems (including legislatures and law enforcement) to achieve social goals, in this case the goals of feminists to improve the situation of women in the home.
A concrete example is the way that domestic violence has been moved from a private issue to a legal issue; not only does the law now prohibit a husband from beating his wife, but the police are expected to intervene and prosecute cases where it happens, rather than merely turning a blind eye to it.

Describing the law or the systems that law works through as "technology" would not be out of place in legal philosophy or legal academic discourse generally.
See:

Joshua A. T. Fairfield, "Keeping Up: Law As Social Technology", in Runaway Technology: Can Law Keep Up? (Cambridge University Press, 2021)
Christian Turner, "Models of Law", 2018 U. Ill. L. Rev. 1293 (2018)


Its a perfectly cromulent usage
Words mean what we agree they mean; after all, all words are made up.
Merriam-Webster defines technology as:

1

a: the practical application of knowledge especially in a particular area : ENGINEERING sense 2
medical technology
b
: a capability given by the practical application of knowledge
a car's fuel-saving technology

2
: a manner of accomplishing a task especially using technical processes, methods, or knowledge
new technologies for information storage
3
: the specialized aspects of a particular field of endeavor
educational technology

While the most common usage of the word "technology" is the practical application of scientific knowledge to engineering, there is no reason why it can't refer to applying any type of knowledge to any field.
In that sense, describing the law as a technology applied to society is perfectly sensible. We might also describe democracy, politics, protest, equality, or the family as social technologies.
However, this is not, in general, the way lawyers think about it, for much the same reason that engineers don't think too much about the underlying science on a day-to-day basis -  you don't need to think about it in any particular way to use it.
